# Changing background color of the screen based on the answers of the quiz app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button, uibutton, background-color

I've built a quiz app on flutter dart with the help of this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0uinJvhNxI&ab_channel=Academind
In addition to this, i want to change the background color of the final screen which simply prints a message e.g. "You're good" ,"You're average", "You're bad" based on the final score which gets calculated with each selection of the answer (through the button click).
My questions, answers along with score are:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _questionIndex = 0;
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  var _total_score = 0;
  String getText = '';
  final _questions = const [
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s your favourite color?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Blue', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'Red', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Green', 'score': 3},
        {'text': 'White', 'score': 1}
      ]
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite animal?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Rabbit', 'score': 3},
        {'text': 'Snake', 'score': 11},
        {'text': 'Elepehant', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Lion', 'score': 9}
      ]
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite subject?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'A', 'score': 3},
        {'text': 'B', 'score': 11},
        {'text': 'C', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'D', 'score': 9}
      ]
    }
  ];
```

What i've done:
I successfully changed the background color on the basis of total score using this code:

```
  Color colorSelect() {
    Color color;
    if (resultScore <= 16) {
      color = Colors.orange;
    } else if (resultScore == 16) {
      color = Colors.blue;
    } else if (resultScore == 32) {
      color = Colors.green;
    } else {
      color = Colors.white;
    }
    return color;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: colorSelect()),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          resultPhrase,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),),);}}
```

But i want to change the color on some conditions which are:

1. fav color selected = blue, fav animal selected= rabbit, fav subject selected= A then the background color should be "Blue".
2. when fav animal selected= Lion, regardless of what fav subject and fav color is selected then the background color should be "Orange".
3. when the fav subject selected= C, regardless of what fav color and fav animal is selected then the background color should be "Yellow".
4. In all other cases, the background color should be "White".

I am getting "Score" of the selected answer through this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(questions[questionIndex]['questionText']),
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((answer) {
          //text = answerQuestion(answer['score']),
          return Answer(() => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text']);
        }).toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

But I'm unable to get "Text" of the selected answer. How can i do it?

Comment: Could you show the code for selecting an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the build method is in a StatefulWidget, you need to trigger `setState()` method whenever you update the resultScore. What this does is that it will trigger the build method and thus rebuilding your interface, hence updating the background color based on the `colorSelect` method For example

```dart
void selectAnswer(answer) {
    resultScore = answer['score'];
    setState() {};
}
```